# How to deal with oil and water mix when pumping oil from ocean in new Tekkit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

When pumping oil out at sea in the new Minecraft Tekkit, how can you deal with the mixture of water and oil that you get? Is there a way to "sort" them?

Comment: for what it's worth there is a liquid router available in feed the beast, dunno about tekkit.

Comment: @Ender, there is! add it as an answer and I'll accept it. Much cleaner solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Minefactory Reloaded mod has a [Liquid Router](http://ftbwiki.org/Liquid_Router) that does exactly what your asking for.

[image]

> The Liquid Router acts as a filter for liquids. It has six input/output faces, each with a set color: purple for the top face, blue for the north, yellow for the east, green for the south, red for the west, and black for the bottom face. It has a simple GUI with six colored slots for each of the faces; adding a liquid to any of these slots will set the router to filter that liquid to the corresponding input/output face. The Liquid Router is compatible with Buildcraft Waterproof Pipes and Thermal Expansion Liquiducts; however, it does not work with Redpower Fluid Pipes.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few methods to dealing with ocean oil:

- the first (although ugliest) is to simply put make 2 tanks, a water
  tank and oil tank. since liquid can only occupy one tank at a time,
  it will sort itself out(just empty the water tanks often)
- Another(much better) method of seperating the water and oil involves building a wall of gravel/sand. Use a Lily Pad to drop sand/gravel AROUND the 1x1 main oil spout, cutting off the water. This method is perhaps best for oil deposits at sea
- if you have access do it you can also use [Water Strainers](http://tekkitclassic.wikia.com/wiki/Water_Strainer) to separate oil from water. just slap one along the main pipeline. it'll even generate some EU for you in the process (this method also leaves a giant hole in the ocean though, so careful)

Comment: What is a Lily Pad?

Comment: http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Lily_Pad

Comment: I think I'll have to ask for a picture of what you mean, cause I'm not sure I'm understand what I should do with that Lily Pad, haha. Could you supply a demonstration picture?

Comment: The Lily Pad is just something you can stand on and place the blocks of sand/gravel next to it so they fall. I cant really get a picture but I'll try to explain it in detail: you place the Lily pad 2 blocks away from the oil source block, then you shift+walk to the edge of it, finally you place gravel on the outer edge of the lily pad(the side) so the gravel is on the inner part, one away from the source and falls down. repeat this for all sides of the oil (diagonally as well)

Comment: Ah! so the Lily Pads themselves didn't have anything to do with it. It's just a way to do it that doesn't involve horizontal nerd poles from the coast to be able to place the blocks. Makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a water strainer, as they are pretty inexpensive, and destroy the water whilst keeping the oil. To use one, you should just be able to pump the water and oil into it and it just puts out oil. See the tekkit classic wiki for more info.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. You may not have noticed but one of the existing answers already suggests using a water strainer. Please try not to add answers which make points which have already been made before.